# Вывод списка слов в случайном порядке без повторений

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Не могу разобраться с задачкой.

> Создайте программу, которая будет
>   выводить список слов в случайном
>   порядке. На экране должны печататься
>   без повторений все слова из
>   представленного списка.

Вот мой код:

```
spisok = ["Alex", "Kate", "Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin",]
empty_list = []

count = len(spisok)
schetchik = 0

while count != schetchik:
        for item in spisok:
            randitem = random.choice(spisok)
            schetchik += 1
            if randitem not in spisok:
                empty_list += randitem
            else:
                break
        print(empty_list)
```

Скриншот результата выполнения:

[image]

Выводит пустой список.

Comment: А разве `randitem` отсутствует в `spisok`? Вроде как он всегда там будет - мы же из него берем. А значит `empty_list += randitem` никогда не выполнится )

Comment: @kelevra, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: вот [единственный (на данный момент) ответ, который не печатает дубликаты (учитывает *"без повторений"* требование).](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436695/23044)

Comment: Разрешается ли модифицировать исходный список?

Answer (score 8):

Раз пошла такая пьянка, то вот мой вариант:

```
import random
spisok = ["Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin",]
random.shuffle(spisok)
print spisok
```

Comment: ответ игнорирует *"без повторений"* требование из вопроса. [Можно `set()` использовать, чтобы получить список уникальных слов.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436695/23044)

Comment: @jfs, "без повтороний" может означать что каждое слово выдаётся столько раз сколько раз оно встречается в списке. В этом смысле ответ безукоризненный.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы вывести уникальные слова из списка в случайном порядке, используя различные генераторы псевдослучайных чисел:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

words =  ["Alex", "Kate", "Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin",]
unique_words = list(set(words))
random.shuffle(unique_words) # shuffle using default Mersenne Twister generator
random.SystemRandom().shuffle(unique_words)  # OS-provided generator
print("\n".join(unique_words))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import random
spisok = ["Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin",]

while spisok:
    print spisok.pop(random.randint(0, len(spisok)-1))
```

Comment: Я выше про `shuffle` писал, вы бы тогда хоть и это решение привели бы. Только стоило бы уточнить, что эти примеры меняют исходный список (ваш способ вообще его очищает). Но ответ выше памяти зато требует больше.

Привели бы лучше пример, чтобы и список исходный не меняло, и памяти почти не ело ))

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал это так:

```
    import random
    spisok = ["Alex", "Kate", "Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin",]
    empty_list = []
    while len(empty_list) != len(spisok):
            randitem = random.choice(spisok)
            if randitem not in empty_list:
                empty_list.append(randitem)  
    print(empty_list)
```

**Обновление**

Но этот вариант не подходит для длинных списков. А вот @ВОРОН бы сделал так:

```
import random
spisok = ...
empty_list = []
for item in spisok:
    rand_index = random.randint(0, len(empty_list)
    empty_list.insert(rand_index), item)
```

и этот вариант гораздо лучше.

Comment: А я бы `shuffle/random.shuffle` использовал. А то - будет в списке миллион записей и сколько мне ждать надо будет, чтобы размеры списков сравнялись?

Если же самому делать, тогда уж из `spisok` удалять. Тогда и проверка на присутствие в `empty_list` не нужна будет.

Comment: Я пытался исправить текущее решение, а не создать новое.

Comment: Ну указать на ошибку в логике можно было и в комментарии. Потому я и не стал делать свой комментарий ответом. Для ответа не хватало бы разбора примеров с возможными вариантами.

А в текущем виде вы не столько "исправили" решение, сколько замаскировали ошибку (ту, которая будет долго выполняться).

Исправить вариант автора следовало как-то так:

    import random
    spisok = ...
    empty_list = []
    for item in spisok:
        rand_index = random.randint(0, len(empty_list)
        empty_list.insert(rand_index), item)

Тогда скорость заполнения даже миллионов слов будет приемлемой.

Comment: Да Ваш вариант гораздо лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Можно даже так:

```
>>> import random
>>> array = ["Alex", "Kate", "Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin"]
>>> print(*random.sample(set(array), len(set(array))), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

[[@BOPOH](/users/5079/bopoh)](/users/5079/bopoh),

> чтобы и список исходный не меняло, и памяти почти не ело ))

Challange accepted

```
import random
def iter_shuffled(l):
    indices = list(range(len(l)))
    random.shuffle(indices)
    for i in indices:
        yield l[i]

spisok = ["Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin",]
for item in iter_shuffled(spisok):
    print (item)
```

**UPDATE**
Т.к. при копировании списка элементами нового списка станут ссылки на исходные значения, то можно обойтись и без списка индексов:

```
import random
def iter_shuffled(l):
    new_list = list(l)
    random.shuffle(new_list)
    for item in new_list:
        yield item
```

Но тогда смысл оформлять код в виде функции-итератора практически теряется и код можно сократить до следующих строк:

```
import random
spisok = ["Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin",]
new_list = list(spisok)
random.shuffle(new_list)
print new_list
```

Comment: А чем `indices = list(range(len(l)))` лучше `another_list = list(spisok)` и последующего shuffle на нем? Только тем, что вместо строк числа? Ну так исходный массив мог быть числовым.

Comment: @BOPOH, можно и list(spisok), все равно это внутри будут ссылки на исходные строки. Но это было бы не так интересно :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

inp = ["Alex", "Kate", "Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin"]
l = list(set(inp))
random.shuffle(l)
print (l)
```

Comment: Вывод будет в случайном порядке без повторений?

Comment: это не гарантирует случайный порядок. Попробуйте с `PYTHONHASHSEED=0` переменной окружения запустить. Поэтому я убрал этот вариант из [более поздних](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/436695/4) версий [оригинальной версии своего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/436695/1)

Comment: @jfs, я бы вопрос понял как "в любом порядке", а не то, что надо именно всё перемешать в случайном.

Answer (score 0):

> чтобы и список исходный не меняло, и памяти почти не ело ))

```
from random import shuffle
lst = [ "Alex", "Kate", "Love", "World", "Peace", "Freddie Mercury" ]
idx = list(range(len(lst)))
shuffle(idx)
while idx:
    print(lst[idx.pop()])
```

Comment: Ну так памяти здесь потребляется 2N, если не байты считать, а кол-во элементов, ведь исходный массив мог быть числовым.

Есть вариант через рекурсию, но я не знаю, сколько памяти на это решение уйдет. Может быть, накладные расходы будут большими, да и предел рекурсии быстро может быть достигнут. Да и решение не совсем чистое - исходный список все-таки меняется при работе, но затем возвращается в исходное.

Есть еще один вариант с рекурсией, но он "очень и очень псевдослучайный". Там так же рекурсия используется, но глубина ее всего log N.

Еще один "очень псевдослучайный" вариант пока зреет )

Comment: А битовые вектора в Python есть? 

Если да, то все решается с дополнительной памятью N бит за N циклов получения случайного числа. Аналогично разрешению коллизий при хэшировании с открытой адресацией.

Comment: Ну прям спектакль "Много шума из ничего". Автор В.И. Хэшспир:) Зато узнал много нового.

Answer (score 0):

Я исправил код:

```python
import  random

spisok = ["Alex", "Kate", "Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin",]
empty_list = []

count = len(spisok)
schetchik = 0

while count != schetchik:
    for item in spisok:
        item = random.choice(spisok)
        empty_list.append(item)
        schetchik += 1
    print(empty_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Код из [ответа Артёма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418899/1365) не выполняет изначальное условие задачи: "*...выводить список слов в случайном порядке. На экране должны **печататься без повторений** все слова из представленного списка...*" 
так как будут выводиться повторы из списка - отсутствует проверка на уже выбранные элементы. 
Чуть поправим:

```
import  random
spisok = ["Alex", "Kate", "Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin",]
empty_list = list()
count = len(spisok)
schetchik = 0

while count != schetchik:
    for i in spisok:
        item = random.choice(spisok)
        if item in empty_list:
            print("Есть такие данные в новом списке!")
        else:
            empty_list.append(item)
            schetchik += 1
    print(empty_list) # можно оставить вывод в for - увидим все попытки поиска, либо вывести из цикла.
```

Как уже замечали авторы в комментариях, есть более краткий и практичный вариант с созданием среза изначального списка:

```
import random
spisok_slov = ["кот", "кот", "код", "код", "ток", "ток", "ток", "ток", "тук-тук", "мак", "крот", "плот", "кнут"]
final_no_repeat_list = list(set(spisok_slov[:]))
random.shuffle(final_no_repeat_list)
print(final_no_repeat_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

ВНИМАНИЕ! это код чтобы выдавал только одно рандомное слово из списка слов, вдруг понадобиться.

```
words = "муравей бабуин барсук медведь".split() #.split делает список из слов данные в '' k_word = len(words)  # считаем слова
import random

random_word = random.randint(0, k_word)  # выберает рандомное число от 0 до последнего слово в списке (Пример: 34)
finish_word = words[random_word] # выбирает 34+1 слово в списке (+1 потому что списки начинаются с 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Перелопатить с [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```py
import random

words =  list(set(["Alex", "Kate", "Love", "Alex", "World", "Peace", "Plutin"]))
random.shuffle(words)
print(words)

['Plutin', 'Love', 'Alex', 'Peace', 'Kate', 'World']
```

Comment: Точно такой ответ уже есть

Answer (score 0):

Метод `shuffle` меняет список, если нужно без изменения исходного списка, то лучше использовать метод `sample`, там также можно указывать количество выводимых уникальных слов

```
import random
spisok = ["Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin"]
n = len(spisok) #количество слов, которые надо вывести
print(*random.sample(spisok,n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вод мой код, строго не судите)

```
import random
WORDS = ["Alex", "Kate", "Love", "World", "Peace", "Putin",]
WORDS_NEW = []
while len(WORDS_NEW) != len(WORDS):
    rand = random.choice(WORDS)
    if rand not in WORDS_NEW:
        WORDS_NEW.append(rand)
print(WORDS_NEW)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.