# Разный порядок элементов при добавлении в словарь

Tags: python

Имеется простейшая программа:

```
d = dict()

d["A"] = "A"
d["B"] = "B"
d["C"] = "C"

print(d)
```

Запускаем несколько раз и получаем разный вывод:

```
{'C': 'C', 'B': 'B', 'A': 'A'}
{'A': 'A', 'C': 'C', 'B': 'B'}
{'A': 'A', 'B': 'B', 'C': 'C'}
{'C': 'C', 'A': 'A', 'B': 'B'}
{'B': 'B', 'C': 'C', 'A': 'A'}
```

Почему так происходит? Вроде бы должна использоваться одинаковая хэш-функция и порядок при каждом запуске должен быть одинаковым.

Что интересно, следующий код выдаёт десять одинаковых строк:

```
for i in range(10):
    d = dict()

    d["A"] = "A"
    d["B"] = "B"
    d["C"] = "C"

    print(d)
```

(Возможно, зависит от платформы и/или версии, поэтому сразу укажу, что использовался Python 3.5.1 x86 на Windows.)

Comment: при запуске тестов полезно явно `PYTHONHASHSEED` определять (как это, например, tox делает), чтобы можно было воспроизвести результаты. [можно даже эксплуатировать "hash randomization" (`-R`), чтобы слова в случайном порядке вывести](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436695/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Вроде бы должна использоваться одинаковая хэш-функция

В Python 2.7 так и происходит, а вот начиная с Python 3.3 в функцию `hash()` введена рандомизация при каждом запуске интерпретатора (см. [security fix](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2012-March/009394.html)).

И теперь, если выполнить вот такой вот код:

```
print('A: %d' % hash('A'))
print('B: %d' % hash('B'))
print('C: %d' % hash('C'))
```

то Python 2.7 всегда выдаёт одинаковый ответ

```
A: -269909568
B: -141909181
C: -13908798
```

и словарь всегда печатается в виде `{'A': 'A', 'C': 'C', 'B': 'B'}`

А вот у 3.5 ответ всегда разный

```
A: -2050324995
B: -224727271
C: -1073853401
{'B': 'B', 'A': 'A', 'C': 'C'}

A: -1049022696
B: 1500164900
C: 1196027868
{'A': 'A', 'C': 'C', 'B': 'B'}
```

Кстати, об этом написано в доках к [`object.__hash__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> **Note:** By default, the **hash**() values of str, bytes and datetime objects are “salted” with an unpredictable random value. Although they remain constant within an individual Python process, they are not predictable between repeated invocations of Python.
>
> This is intended to provide protection against a denial-of-service caused by carefully-chosen inputs that exploit the worst case performance of a dict insertion, O(n^2) complexity. See http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html for details.
>
> Changing hash values affects the iteration order of dicts, sets and other mappings. Python has never made guarantees about this ordering (and it typically varies between 32-bit and 64-bit builds).
>
> See also PYTHONHASHSEED.
>
> > Changed in version 3.3: Hash randomization is enabled by default.

Comment: Python 2.7 может другие значения вернуть. Также `-R` опция включает "hash randomization" и до Python 3.3.